# Is it possible to get past startup scripts in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'd like to review some startup scripts that were used with terminated and deleted instances in Google Cloud. Is there a way to get these via gcloud or the GCP console?

Comment: You can view the output from a Linux shutdown script by Connecting to the instance and running the following command: `sudo journalctl -u google-shutdown-scripts.service`

Comment: If the instance is terminated, but not deleted, you can go to it, and review the detail. The startup script will be there, in the configuration.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Sorry, yes I should specify they are terminated and deleted.

Comment: I tested the audit logs, and it's not logged. I have no option

Comment: @Imonninger if you have a snapshot of the deleted instance you can still view the startup script but need to [Restore from the snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-snapshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For terminated and deleted instances reviewing startup scripts is not possible without using a machine image, as [Machine image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images) offers a quick backup of a VM as a whole, in contrast to other features like PD snapshots and custom images.

Comment: Follow-up, what would be easiest solution for shipping logs including the startup script? Is there perhaps something I could configure in a GCP managed instance group? Or, would I need to run a logging agent on the instances individually?

Comment: Google Cloud's operations suite have agents for collecting logs check this documentation on [Google Cloud operations suite agents](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent) for multiple instances Google Cloud's operations suite also have several ways to install using automation tools accross multiple VMs see this documentation on [Managing agents on multiple VMs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/fleet-installation) for your guide.